# C++ pass class method as parameter

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, esp32

I'm working with the ESP32. Currently I am migrating my library from an ESP8266 codebase.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
m_pubSubClient.setCallback( std::bind(&CL::callbackHandler, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));
```

But it seems like the author of the PubSubClient library has changed the signature.

```
// old
#define MQTT_CALLBACK_SIGNATURE std::function<void(char*, uint8_t*, unsigned int)> callback
//new 
#define MQTT_CALLBACK_SIGNATURE void (*callback)(char*, uint8_t*, unsigned int)
```

I can't figure out, how to do that with the new signature.

Comment: Read up upon [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: What exactly is unclear about passing a plain function pointer? You can't pass a function object any more. Pretty clear. That's it.

Comment: Ok, but why is that not possible anymore and is there a workaround, because I need this feature :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As plain function pointers can not be bound to member functions, you basically just have three choices left: you can declare CL::callbackHandler as a static member function, make it a free function or use a lambda expression (without closures), like

```
m_pubSubClient.setCallback([](char* param1, uint8_t* param2, unsigned int param3) {
    // handling the event
});
```

Comment: But I can't get a this reference in a lambda function without changing the signature, do I?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If none of the pointers in the parameter list are for user data, the only thing you can do is falling back to global or static variables.

Comment: Best example for "new is always better" being not true. Thanks for your time :)